# Merge the query results,optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql,two tables：test(one) and review(many).
My goal:from review for one in the corresponding number

```
SELECT t.ID,t.TITLE,COALESCE(COUNT(r.ID),0) `count`
FROM `test` t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN review r
    ON t.ID = r.REVIEW_OBJ_ID 
WHERE r.REVIEW_TYPE = '4'
ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

Output:

```
ID                                  TITLE      count
402884f657e0a6d20157e0a82cc90000    brother    2
```

test table(A small portion of the data)

```
SELECT t.ID,t.TITLE
FROM `test` t;
```

Output:

```
ID                                  TITLE
40284c8157ad8e7d0157ad8f86880000    1234567890123456789012345
402884f657e0a6d20157e0a82cc90000    brother
402884f657e0a6d20157e11967a20036    fg
402884f657e51eff0157e54cd8610004    AAA
402884f657e652fb0157e65642750000    BBB
0000000057f4dc900157f4ea9edd0000    VVV
00000000580065c5015800746d750000    CCC
00000000580065c501581d9f04f0000b    TTT
```

And I want get this:

```
ID                                  TITLE                      count 
402884f657e0a6d20157e0a82cc90000    brother                    2
402884f657e652fb0157e65642750000    BBB                        0
00000000580065c501581d9f04f0000b    TTT                        0
402884f657e0a6d20157e11967a20036    fg                         0
0000000057f4dc900157f4ea9edd0000    VVV                        0
40284c8157ad8e7d0157ad8f86880000    1234567890123456789012345  0
402884f657e51eff0157e54cd8610004    AAA                        0
00000000580065c5015800746d750000    CCC                        0
```

so,I tried this and it worked:

```
SELECT t.ID,t.TITLE, COALESCE(r.c,0) `count`
FROM `test` t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT r.REVIEW_OBJ_ID obj_id, COUNT(r.ID) c 
    FROM review r,`test` t
    WHERE r.REVIEW_TYPE = '4' 
        AND t.ID = r.REVIEW_OBJ_ID
) r ON r.obj_id = t.ID
ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

But I have two questions:

1. It feels I can use one-time select to found out result,but I use two-times select.Can I optimize it?
2. Add a `count`(redundant) in the test table fields, whether it is a better choice.

/REVIEW_TYPE and REVIEW_OBJ_ID decide which object is reviewed,just like I use "REVIEW_TYPE='4'" to contact the `test` table/

```
drop table if exists user_doctor_review;
create table review
(
   ID                   varchar(64) not null,
   USER_ID              varchar(64),
   DOCTOR_ID            varchar(64),
   REVIEW_TYPE          varchar(1),
   REVIEW_OBJ_ID        varchar(64),
   SERVICE_SCORE        int(6),
   REVIEW_CONTENT       varchar(600),
   REVIEW_TIME          datetime,
   POID                 varchar(64),
   IS_ANONYMITY         varchar(1),
   CHECKED_STATUS       varchar(1),
   STATUS               varchar(1),
   REPLY_CONTENT        varchar(600),
   REPLY_TIME           datetime,
   DOCTOR_IS_READ       varchar(1),
   primary key (ID)
);
```

Comment: can you share structure of your tables like what is review_obj_id ?

Comment: I don't know whether I express clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with one `SELECT` statement with this query

```
SELECT test.ID, test.TITLE, count(review.ID) as count from test
left join review on test.ID = review.REVIEW_OBJ_ID
where review.REVIEW_TYPE = 4 or review.ID is null
group by test.ID
```

I have created a SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a178/15

**Explanation:**
The key points are:

```
or review.ID is null
```

because it will make the query list the tests with no reviews, and

```
group by test.ID
```

this will get the correct review counts related to the test.

Results:

```
ID                                  TITLE                       count
--------------------------------    -------------------------   -----
0000000057f4dc900157f4ea9edd0000    VVV                         0
00000000580065c5015800746d750000    CCC                         0
00000000580065c501581d9f04f0000b    TTT                         1
40284c8157ad8e7d0157ad8f86880000    1234567890123456789012345   0
402884f657e0a6d20157e0a82cc90000    brother                     2
402884f657e0a6d20157e11967a20036    fg                          0
402884f657e51eff0157e54cd8610004    AAA                         0
402884f657e652fb0157e65642750000    BBB                         0
```

Comment: HaHa, I get it. Thanks.